# Chromium giving a Bus error (core dumped) error after manual fsck

Tags: chromium, fsck

Before running manual fsck everything worked just fine on ubuntu 19.10.

When launching chromium from the terminal it outputs `Bus error (core dumped)

`
Executing these commands:

```
rm ~/.cache/chromium
rm ~/.config/chromium
```

both returned:

```
rm: cannot remove 'file path' No such file or directory
```

I also tried:
`sudo apt-get update` with no success

I cannot uninstall chromium from the Ubuntu software Application. Uninstalling it from the terminal doesn't work either

Comment: My own issue has been fixed by updating ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04